# Loading contents of an NSArray into a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have populated an NSArray called **teacherNames*. The data successfully comes in from a Core data entity called Teachers using the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Teachers"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teachers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"teacherName" ascending:YES]];
request.entity = entity;
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"teacherName"]];

NSError *error = nil;
self.teacherNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[self.tableViewTeacherNames reloadData];
```

I can see that there are there as when I type the following in the debug window:

```
print self.teacherNames.count
```

it returns the correct number in the array.

However when I try to use the `NSArray` to populate the table using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewTeacherNames cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"teacherCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSString *currentItem = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"teacherName"]; - ERROR LINE
cell.textLabel.text = currentItem;
return cell;
}
```

I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb88ce30'
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're attempting to do objectForKey on an NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`. The latter belongs to `NSDictionary` whereas the former to any `NSObject` descendant